# Which list has the tags in sharepoint 2010 so I can use the list for Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010, autocomplete, tags

I am using SPServices to do autocomplete and can pull from different lists. The one list I cannot find however is the "Tag" or "Tags" list. Does anyone know where it is so I can query directly from it? Thank you and let me know if this is confusing so I can elaborate.

Im new at SharePoint coming from much lighter web dev so please dont be afraid to tell me I dont know what I am talking about too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the "U2U CAML Query Builder", it looks like there is the `TaxonomyHiddenList` which can be queried against. It is hidden so I am assuming you need "owner" rights but it works for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready (function() {

    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: true,
        listName: "TaxonomyHiddenList",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields>" +
            "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
            "</ViewFields>",
        completefunc: AttachAutoComplete
    });
});

function AttachAutoComplete(xmlResponse) {
    var domElementArray = $( "[nodeName=z:row]", xmlResponse.responseXML );

    var dataMap = domElementArray.map(function() {
        return {
            value: $(this).attr('ows_Title')
        };
    });

    var data = dataMap.get();

    $("input#inputAutoComplete").autocomplete({
        source: data,
        select: function(e, ui){
            alert(ui.item['value']);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var sharePointSite = "<Site Collection URL>";
   var listToSearch = "Employee"; // enter your Contacts list name here


   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#Search").keyup(function (e) {
           var query = $(this).val();
           var lists = new SPAPI_Lists(sharePointSite);
           var items = lists.getListItems(
                listToSearch,  // listName
                '',     // viewName
                '', // CAML query 
           '<ViewFields><FieldRef Name="Title"/><FieldRef  Name="Name"/></ViewFields>', // Use this option to retrieve only specific rows 
                10, // rowLimit
                '' // queryOptions
            );

       if (items.status == 200) {
           var rows = items.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('z:row');

           var results = "<ul>";

           if (rows.length > 0) {
               for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                   results += "<li><a style='color:white' href='" + sharePointSite    + "/Lists/" + listToSearch + "/AllItems.aspx?ID=" + rows.item(i).getAttribute('ows_ID') + "'>" + rows.item(i).getAttribute('ows_Title') + '</a></li>';
               }
               results += "</ul>";               }
           else {
               results = "";
           }
           suggest(results);
       }
       else {
           alert('There was an error: ' + items.statusText);
       }
   }).change();

   $('#suggestionsList').click(function () {
       $('#Search').val($(this).text());
       $('#suggestions').fadeOut();
   });

   });
    function suggest(inputString) {
        if (inputString.length == 0) {
            $('#suggestions').fadeOut();
        } else {
           $('#suggestions').fadeIn();
           $('#suggestionsList').html(inputString);
       }
    }

    function fill(thisValue) {
        $('#suggestion').val(thisValue);
        setTimeout("$('#suggestions').fadeOut();", 600);
    }

 </script>
```